# MySQL JOIN com ou sem foreign key?

Tags: mysql, join, chave-estrangeira

Qual a diferença entre relacionar 2 tabelas utilizando e não utilizando uma foreign key?

Com relação a performance, é recomendável utilizar foreign key para fazer o relacionamento?

Em qual situação seria indispensável e em qual situação seria dispensável utilizar uma foreign key para fazer o relacionamento?

Comment: Uma situação que difere ambos, em uma rápida "resposta", o `foreign key` amarra as tabelas, então geralmente uma não pode ter dados se a "ligação" com outra tabela (ou até a mesma tabela), podemos dizer que é um vinculo "obrigatório". Assim que tiver tempo, tentarei formular uma resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qual a diferença entre relacionar 2 tabelas utilizando e não utilizando uma `foreign key`?

**R:** a diferença é que quando você não usa `foreign key` para relacionar suas tabelas a restrição do relacionamento caso exista, terá de ser controlada por sua aplicação, isso pode ser uma grande desvantagem pois a verificação de integridade de suas tabelas ficará decentralizada diferentemente de quando o servidor de banco controla a integridade dos relacionamentos.

Com relação a performance, é recomendável utilizar `foreign key` para fazer o relacionamento?

**R:** Quando configuramos uma `foreign key` o que o servidor de banco faz na verdade é criar uma `trigger` interna, por isso pode verificar a integridade referencial de cada linha inserida, atualizada ou apagada. Isso acarreta em overhead na execução de operações em lote por exemplo onde muitas alterações são processadas pelo servidor em uma operação, imagina que sua aplicação vai fazer uma importação de dados de movimentos de um supermercado onde acontecem milhares de vendas em um dia; nesses tipos de situação a utilização de `foreign keys` afetam muito na performance, o que muitos programadores costumam fazer é desabilitar a verificação das `foreign key` antes de operações custosas, exemplo mysql:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Em qual situação seria indispensável e em qual situação seria dispensável utilizar uma `foreign key` para fazer o relacionamento?

**R:** Isso depende muito da regra de negócio da sua aplicação mas no geral são indispensáveis quando a existência da entidade de  uma tabela depende de uma outra e esta tem grande importância no sistema e também é acessada por locais diferentes na aplicação; requerendo uma centralização. Agora tabelas onde `foreign keys` são dispensáveis pode ser para entidades de cadastros secundários que não possuem grande importância na aplicação, mas isso depende muito.

Referência: https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html